# mysql : using FK to delete rows from parent table that dont match with child table

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say there are 2 tables with the following definitions:
`photos_libraries ( id , name )`
and 
`photos ( id , library_id )`

when a row in photos is deleted or updated I'd like to run the functionality of :

```
delete from photos_libraries where id not in ( select library_id from photos )
```

Is there a way to do that using a foreign key ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: thanks , but i think 'on delete cascade' only does "delete from photos where id='the_library_id' " (where the_library_id is the deleted row's library_id ). thus, when the library has 2 photos and  you delete one , it deletes the library.